# How do I edit an XML file in SimpleXML, based on the contents of the XML, if there are multiple values of the same tag?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

Say I have an XML file like this.

```
<users>
  <user>
    <username>desbest</username>
    <email>desbest@example.com</email>
    <password>testpass1</password>
  </user>
  <user>
    <username>demo</username>
    <email>nobody@example.com</email>
    <password>demo</password>
  </user>
</users>
```

How do I use XPath to select the `desbest` user, then use php to edit the password under the `desbest` user, and save it as a file?

I have searched Google and Stack Overflow and I haven't found the answer.

Here is my current code.

```
// print_r($xml);
$newpass = "mynewpass";
// $newpass = password_hash($newpass, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
$nodes = $xml->xpath(sprintf(" //users/user[(username = \"$myusername\")] ")); 
// print_r($nodes);
// $nodes[0]->password = "$newpass";
$domnode = dom_import_simplexml($nodes[0]);
$nodepath = $domnode->getNodePath();
// $xml = $xml->$nodepath->password = $newpass;

// $danodepath = $nodes[0]->getNodePath();

// print_r($nodes);
// $xml->users->user["(username = \"$myusername\")"] = "$newpass";
print_r($xml);
echo "<hr>";
print_r($nodepath);
```

Comment: post your current php code showing your efforts

Comment: Have you read the PHP documentation for XPath? http://php.net/manual/en/class.domxpath.php

Comment: Which part are you having trouble with? Finding the node with xpath, modifying the password, or reading/writing the file?

Comment: I have posted my current code.

Comment: @Daniel Yes I have

Comment: @iainn Modifying the password.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this just with `SimpleXML` - you don't need to involve `DOMDocument` at all.

The `xpath` method returns the `<user>` element you're looking for. You can then modify it simply by updating the *password* property (or add new ones, or attributes, etc). This updates the underlying `SimpleXMLElement` object, which you can then write back to the file as a string using `asXML`.

```
$filename = 'file.xml';
$sxml = simplexml_load_file($filename);

$username = "desbest";
$user = $sxml->xpath("./user[./username = '{$username}']")[0];
$user->password = 'testpassCHANGED';

file_put_contents($filename, $sxml->asXML());
```

See https://eval.in/923654 for an example

Answer (score 0):

Example with DOMDocument:

```
$source = '<users>
  <user>
    <username>desbest</username>
    <email>desbest@example.com</email>
    <password>testpass1</password>
  </user>
  <user>
    <username>demo</username>
    <email>nobody@example.com</email>
    <password>demo</password>
  </user>
</users>';

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom->formatOutput = true;
$dom->loadXML($source);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$myusername = htmlspecialchars("desbest", ENT_XML1 | ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
$expression = sprintf('/users/user[(username="%s")]', $myusername);

$users = $xpath->query($expression);
if($users->length) {
    $user = $users->item(0);
    $password = $xpath->query('password', $user)->item(0);
    $password->nodeValue = 'new password';
}

file_put_contents('filename.xml', $dom->saveXML());
```